# Run macro on another worksheet from one sheet Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Excel Workbooks (WB1, WB2). I want to be able to run a Macro from WB1 that will run a macro on WB2. The macro I want to run on Wb2 is already in WB2. Basically I want to click a button that will run the WB2 macro on WB2.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have?

Comment: @steph if you found my answer acceptable, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.Run` to run a macro on a different workbook. Assuming `Wb2` is already open, and the macro you want to run is called `MacroName` then you can use the following ...

```
Application.Run "Wb2!MacroName"
```

from within `Wb1`

Comment: Doesn't that run the Macro on Wb1 instead of Wb2?

Comment: It depends what is in the macro.

Comment: The macro would loop through the tabs and do some calculations. When I just do an Application.Run, it tries to run the Macro on Wb1. Should I just open Wb2, Run the method, then close Wb2?

Comment: You need to update the macro in `Wb2` so it uses `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ThisWorkbook` which will reference the workbook you wrote the code in. A simple way to change this is to use the search function ctrl+f on your code and replace your workbook name with `ThisWorkBook`.

Credit to @3-14159265358979323846264 for catching my mistake.

Comment: You mean `ThisWorkbook`? `ActiveWorkbook` is making the macro in `Wb2` run on `Wb1`

Comment: Ah my mistake, I read the question incorrectly. I though @steph wanted to run code from Wb1 in Wb2. Apologies.

Comment: No apologies necessary :0) Glad you agree because I was starting to wonder if i knew what i was doing!!

Comment: It may work, but I might look to avoid using Activeworkbook, especially if you are going to be switching between workbooks.  You can use it to set the variable (i.e. `Set thisWB = activeworkbook`), then use `thisWB` in the macro.